# springboot fails to access static resources

Tags: java

2023-01-12 22:58:37.869  WARN 6052 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /2.jpg
2023-01-12 22:58:37.952  WARN 6052 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /2.jpg

Setting the profile still does not solve the problem

Comment: ok nice, and what is the question?

Comment: jpg image in resources directory cannot be accessed in browser

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include how you've set up the application, what you are attempting and what you expect to happen. Consider reading [ask] or taking the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

Unlike what the spring-boot states, to get your spring-boot jar to serve the content: you had to add specifically register my src/main/resources/static content through this config class:

```
   @Configuration
   public class StaticResourceConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
        "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
        "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/" };

   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
        .addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
   }
  }
```